# drop down list value in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want to add a value to the drop down list that cannot be selected, like a title.
Ex: I have a month drop down list. The very first item should be "select month" this should not be selected. And next is from January to december. How can I do that?

And this is my current code.

```
string selectmonth = "select * from tblmonth";
SqlCommand scmselect = new SqlCommand(selectmonth, scnbuboy);

SqlDataReader sdrselect = scmselect.ExecuteReader();

drmonth.DataTextField = "month";
drmonth.DataValueField = "monthID";
drmonth.DataSource = sdrselect;

drmonth.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DdlMonths" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="Select Month" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="January" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="February" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    ....
    <asp:ListItem Text="December" Value="12"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

You can even use a `RequiredFieldValidator` which ignore this item, it considers it as unselected.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqMonth" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DdlMonths"
    InitialValue="-1">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Thanks. Finally got it. I thought I still have to do something to the drop down list itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can add an empty value such as:

```
ddlmonths.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Month", ""))
```

And just add a validation to prevent chosing empty option such as `asp:RequiredFieldValidator`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
your_ddl_id.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("Select","");
```

Answer (score 1):

These are ALL great answers if you want to work that hard.  But my guess is that you already have the items you want for the list coming from a databound element, and only want to add to the top of that list the "Hey, dude - pick one!" option.  Assuming that is the case...

Here's the EASY Answer.  **And it ALWAYS works...**

1. Do your Databound List just like you planned.
2. THEN, in Visual Studio, edit the items on dropdown,
3. Add ONE MANUAL ITEM, make that your "**Select an Item**" choice,
4. Using the properties window for the item in VS2012, check it as selected.  Now close that window.
5. Now, go to the properties box in Visual Studio on the lower left hand (make sure the dropdown is selected), and look for the property "AppendDataBoundItems".
6. It will read False, set this to True.

Now you will get a Drop Down with all of your data items in it, PRECEDED BY your "Select an Item" statement made in the manual item.  Try giving it a default value if possible, this will eliminate any errors you may encounter.  The default is Zero, so if zero is not a problem, then leave it alone, if zero IS a problem, replace the default zero in the item with something that will NOT crash your code.

And stop working so hard...that's what Visual Studio is for.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="">--Select Month--</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">January</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Feburary</asp:ListItem>
    ...
    <asp:ListItem Value="12">December</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Value should be empty for the default selected listitem, then it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a drop down called `ddlMonths`:

```
ddlMonths.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("Select a month","-1");
```

Comment: I have tried:
                string selectmonth = "select * from tblmonths";
                SqlCommand scmselect = new SqlCommand(selectmonth, scnbuboy);
                SqlDataReader sdrselect = scmselect.ExecuteReader();
                drmonth.DataTextField = "month";
                drmonth.DataValueField = "monthID";
                drmonth.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("select a month", "-1"));
                drmonth.DataSource = sdrselect;
                drmonth.DataBind();
                sdrselect.Close();
But only the data from the database appears, not the "select a month"field.

Answer (score 0):

In simple way, Its not possible. Because `DropdownList` contain `ListItem` and it will be selected by default

But, you can use `ValidationControl` for that:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="-1" ID="Req_ID" Display="Dynamic" 
ValidationGroup="g1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ControlID"
Text="*" ErrorMessage="ErrorMessage"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

VB Code:

```
Dim ListItem1 As New ListItem()
ListItem1.Text = "put anything here"
ListItem1.Value = "0"
drpTag.DataBind()
drpTag.Items.Insert(0, ListItem1)
```

View:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CompareValidator" ControlToValidate="drpTag" 
  ValueToCompare="0">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add items to drop down list with value in asp.net using c# just add below codes for example:

```
try
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
    comm = conn.CreateCommand();
    comm.CommandText = "SELECT title,gid from Groups";
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
       dropDownList.Items.Add(new 
       ListItem(dr[0].ToString(),dr[1].ToString()));
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    lblText.Text = e.Message;
}
finally
{
  conn.Close();
}
```