# How do i use cookies to store a different theme colour so it changes on all pages on my site not just the homepage?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, cookies

I am trying to store my theme colour in a cookie so when i click a button it changes the theme on my homepage but it doesn't change it for my other pages.

JavaScript code: - scroll down to see the new code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        document.cookie = "theme=grey";
        return false;
    });
});


let themeColor = document.cookie;
```

html code: this is on my master page.

```
    <div id="footer">
      <div id="footer_content">
    <img src="Images/fasthosts2.png" alt="Fasthostslogo" width="150" height="50"  />
          <div class="foot"></div>

  <button> Change Theme</button>

    </div>  
 </div>
```

links:

```
  <script src="ThemeChanger.js"></script>
```

New and better code but still doesn't work on all pages.
JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ChangeTheme').click(function () {
        document.body.style.setProperty("--color1", "orange")
        document.body.style.setProperty("--color2", "red")
        document.body.style.setProperty("--color3", "white")
        return false;
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
:root {
    --color1: #3366cc;
    --color2: #2d2d2d;
    --color3: white;
}

#header {
    background-color: #3366cc;
    height: 110px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #0099ff;
    border-top: 5px solid #2d2d2d;
    background: linear-gradient(var(--color2), var(--color1));
}

#footer {
    background-color: darkblue;
    height: 150px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 5px solid #0099ff;
    background: linear-gradient(var(--color1), var(--color2));
}
```

HTML:

```
  <asp:Button ID="ChangeTheme" runat="server" Text="Change Theme" Width="110px" CausesValidation="false" BackColor="#99CCFF" BorderColor="#000066" BorderStyle="Solid" />
```

Comment: You can use localStorage instead

Comment: I tried but doesn't work to so i tried using cookies.

Comment: unless you can show me the code because i don't understand java script that good.

Comment: $('button').click(function () {
  localStorage.setItem('isGreyTheme', true)
}


const isGrey = localStorage.getItem('isGreyTheme')
if (isGrey) {
  $('div').css('background', 'grey');
} else {
   // handle other cases
}

Comment: Theres the local storage code. i used.

Comment: Please check my answer below to know more and what was the error you got in console using your code above?

Comment: Check out this -->https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18300/How-to-change-page-theme-in-asp-net-2-0-dynamicall

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i added the code from the website but there is nothing in the dropdownlist.

Comment: [To add values in DDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355032/drop-down-list-value-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to stack overflow

You need to change your code to

```
$("button").click(function () {
    document.cookie = "theme=grey;path=/";
    return false;
});
```

By adding `path=/` you tell the browser to save the cookie on domain level. Otherwise the browser will create the cookie for the specific page you are clicking button on.

Comment: do i have to add anything to the path or do i keep exactly the way you wrote.

Comment: It didn't still does the same thing and only changes the colour for the homepage.

Comment: remove your old cookie first or try it in private browsing

Answer (score 0):

add `;path=/` to your cookies and you can use `cookies` on different pages

[this](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) will help you more

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). I think its the preferred way to go.

To save or update use :

```
localStorage.setItem('theme','value');
```

To get the Value:

```
localStorage.getItem('theme');
```

To clear:

```
localStorage.clear()
```

Comment: I tried using this code but it still just changes it for the homepage.

Comment: Could it be because its using the button tag in the java script code so the other buttons on the other pages stop it from working somehow.

Comment: Im new to java script and asp.net so im really confused

Comment: Do not get confused please read the link given in answer .We are here to help further.After reading the article you will get more clarity.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Marks_The_God Post the related code that you have tried to set the theme!

Comment: @Prashant Pimpale what do you mean.

Comment: for this--> *I tried using this code but it still just changes it for the homepage*

Comment: @PrashantPimpale its the code above posted by devinder.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i tried using the code Devinder posted but it didnt work it does the same thing my code does.

Comment: @Marks_The_God Are you running the check script on every page ? I think what you are thinking of is that changing the css once changes css for whole website.But that is not the case as every new page is individual document and has its own css

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i added the javascript document link to each page. And the button is on the masterpage inside the footer.

Comment: @Marks_The_God  we might need more code snippets to check what's wrong.We cannot predict without more info

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i edited my question there is more code now including the footer.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale is it right on SO to ask someone to contact on personal email or social network ,if you want to help further ?

Comment: Yes, [you can](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305632/asking-for-personal-contact-information-in-comments/305771#305771)

Comment: @Marks_The_God you can find me on https://www.linkedin.com/in/devinder1995/ please contact me there so that i can help you further

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the other pages also read the cookie value and change the style accordingly. It would be helpful if you added all of your code, like the bits that use the variable *themeColor*.